# Microsoft Access - How to create a persistent connection to the linked database between back-end and front-end?

Tags: ms-access, connection, persistence

I have a connection speed problem when someone running a query from a Access database. The delay for loading data significantly increase when a user runs new queries after some minutes of not using the app.

I found [this article](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/performance/linkeddatabase.html) for fixing this issue, I did all the steps but the codes were not working for me! I have one single database and the app working on multi-user environment (9 people).

Does anyone have any solutions/suggestions?

Thanks,
Peyman

Comment: When you say " but the codes were not working for me!" that doesn't help us help you.

Comment: Yes You are right. I should have addressed the issue more specifically. I haven't got any error messages after adding the code to the form. It didn't change anything and the slow connection remained unchanged!

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that a persistent connection does not always fix slow network issues. However in a rather high % of cases it does.

The most easy way to “test” if a persistent connection will fix your issue(s) is to simply open up a linked table in your front end. (Any table will do as long as it is a linked table pointing to your back end). NOW run your code or query. If it runs fast then a persistent connection will help your case. If the above simple 3 second test does NOT fix performance, then a persistent connection while recommend and is a good idea – it will not fix your performance issue.

So try the above. If the above fixes your issues, then you can pursue one of several means to achieve a persistent connection.

Some simple ways to force or always have a connection open to the back end:

Simply open some form bound to a linked table. It could even be a “test” form. Right after you open the form, you can set its visible property = false.

Another way is to define a global record set variable and open that record set on start up to a table in the back end. Eg:

Set rst = currentdb.OpenRecordSet("select * from tblTest")

Keep in mind that if you using a non-compiled application (accDB as opposed to a compiled accDE) than any un-handled error will blow out such global variables and thus your persistent connection will be lost.

So before you go on a wild goose chase you can test with a persistent connection by simply opening a linked table in your front end, minimise it and then run your test code or whatever it is that is slow. If you don’t see a speed up, then the performance issue(s) you have will not be solved by using a persistent connection.

Comment: Thanks Albert for your help. After splitting the database the performance of App decreased due to speed of connection which is normal as the database stored on network drive. I did several things to speed up the connection and to somehow it got better. Regarding persistent connection, as after a minute of inactivity the performance and delay time increase I came across to find a solution for persistent connection

Comment: Not sure what you mean by some delay in time - the persistent connection simply always  keeps the back end file open. It is the open + closing of the file that can take very long time - so keeping a the back end open at all times eliminates the open/close delay - there can never be any issue of "time outs" in this regards.